# Items in the images array of the facebook photo object does not contain a source anymore

Tags: facebook, web-services, facebook-graph-api

We were using photo's from facebook in our application until we noticed today that there was no longer a source field available for the different sizes of the image.

I saw in the [facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) that there should be a field "source" for every item in the images array.

> images | The 4 different stored representations of the photo |
>   Requires access_token | array of objects, containing height, width,
>   and source fields

Here's the json data i get from facebook:

```
{
     "id": "10150916781197589",
     "from": {
        "name": "Thomas Dekiere",
        "id": "641457588"
     },
     "name": "antwerpen",
     "picture": "http://photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/383569_10150916781197589_641457588_12988491_2098011643_s.jpg",
     "source": "http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/383569_10150916781197589_641457588_12988491_2098011643_n.jpg",
     "height": 720,
     "width": 478,
     "images": [
        {
           "width": 1360,
           "height": 2048
        },
        {
           "width": 637,
           "height": 960
        },
        {
           "width": 478,
           "height": 720
        },
        {
           "width": 318,
           "height": 480
        },
        {
           "width": 212,
           "height": 320
        },
        {
           "width": 180,
           "height": 271
        },
        {
           "width": 86,
           "height": 130
        },
        {
           "width": 86,
           "height": 130
        }
     ],
     "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150916781197589&set=a.10150916780582589.528576.641457588&type=1",
     "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
     "created_time": "2012-04-04T13:42:09+0000",
     "position": 1,
     "updated_time": "2012-04-04T13:42:19+0000"
  }
```

as you can see, there's no source field in the images array items.

Is this normal behavior now and is the documentation out dated or is this a facebook bug?

Comment: This question as also asked here, and it has a couple of answers already: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10007851/missing-photo-url-source-of-of-facebook-photo-album

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the facebook service:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/328741343854109

It has been solved :)